# How can I get a count field next to the aggregated group by field in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, count, group-by

I'm working with the restaurant sample data set where the data is like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5728c18870b1f4f542bd7c52"),
    "borough" : "Brooklyn",
    "cuisine" : "American",
    "name" : "Riviera Caterer",
    "restaurant_id" : "40356018"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5728c18870b1f4f542bd7c55"),
    "borough" : "Queens",
    "cuisine" : "Jewish/Kosher",
    "name" : "Tov Kosher Kitchen",
    "restaurant_id" : "40356068"
}
```

(skipped some fields which were not needed)

What I'd like to do is basically group the data set by cuisine, with the counts and cuisine next to each other, much like:

```
select count(1) as Count, cuisine 
from restaurants 
group by cuisine
```

Would yield

```
 Count | Cuisine
 --------------
   10  | American 
    5  | Indian
```

Trying out

```
db.restaurants.aggregate([
    {"$group" : {_id:"$cuisine", 
                 count_1:{$sum:1}}}
])
```

Results in result like this:

```
{ "_id" : "American ", "count_1" : 6183 }
{ "_id" : "Bakery", "count_1" : 691 }
{ "_id" : "Irish", "count_1" : 190 }
{ "_id" : "Chicken", "count_1" : 410 }
{ "_id" : "Ice Cream, Gelato, Yogurt, Ices", "count_1" : 348 }
{ "_id" : "Egyptian", "count_1" : 14 }
{ "_id" : "Jewish/Kosher", "count_1" : 316 }
{ "_id" : "Delicatessen", "count_1" : 321 }
{ "_id" : "Indonesian", "count_1" : 8 }
{ "_id" : "Russian", "count_1" : 88 }
{ "_id" : "Spanish", "count_1" : 637 }
{ "_id" : "Chinese", "count_1" : 2418 }
{ "_id" : "Hamburgers", "count_1" : 433 }
{ "_id" : "Hotdogs", "count_1" : 34 }
{ "_id" : "Sandwiches/Salads/Mixed Buffet", "count_1" : 255 }
{ "_id" : "Pancakes/Waffles", "count_1" : 16 }
{ "_id" : "Turkish", "count_1" : 70 }
{ "_id" : "Caribbean", "count_1" : 657 }
{ "_id" : "Donuts", "count_1" : 479 }
{ "_id" : "Bagels/Pretzels", "count_1" : 168 }
```

Is it possible to get the data like:

```
{ "American" : 6183 }
{ "Bakery"   : 691 }
{ "Irish"    : 190 }
{ "Chicken"  : 410 }
{ "Ice Cream, Gelato, Yogurt, Ices" : 348 }
{ "Egyptian" : 14 }
{ "Jewish/Kosher" : 316 }
{ "Delicatessen": 321 }
```

and so on?

Tried using projection like so:

```
db.restaurants.aggregate(
    { $group: { "_id": {cuisine:"$cuisine"},
                "Count":  {"$sum":1}
              }
    },
    { "$project":
       { "_id": 0,
         "Cuisine": "$_id.cuisine",
         "Total":"$Count",
        }
     }
   )
```

But didn't quite get it:

```
{ "Cuisine" : "American ", "Total" : 6183 }
{ "Cuisine" : "Bakery", "Total" : 691 }
{ "Cuisine" : "Irish", "Total" : 190 }
{ "Cuisine" : "Chicken", "Total" : 410 }
{ "Cuisine" : "Ice Cream, Gelato, Yogurt, Ices", "Total" : 348 }
{ "Cuisine" : "Egyptian", "Total" : 14 }
{ "Cuisine" : "Jewish/Kosher", "Total" : 316 }
{ "Cuisine" : "Delicatessen", "Total" : 321 }
{ "Cuisine" : "Indonesian", "Total" : 8 }
{ "Cuisine" : "Russian", "Total" : 88 }
{ "Cuisine" : "Spanish", "Total" : 637 }
{ "Cuisine" : "Chinese", "Total" : 2418 }
{ "Cuisine" : "Hamburgers", "Total" : 433 }
{ "Cuisine" : "Hotdogs", "Total" : 34 }
{ "Cuisine" : "Sandwiches/Salads/Mixed Buffet", "Total" : 255 }
{ "Cuisine" : "Pancakes/Waffles", "Total" : 16 }
{ "Cuisine" : "Turkish", "Total" : 70 }
{ "Cuisine" : "Caribbean", "Total" : 657 }
{ "Cuisine" : "Donuts", "Total" : 479 }
{ "Cuisine" : "Bagels/Pretzels", "Total" : 168 }
```

Basically, I want the count next the group by field, but in MongoDB.

Comment: You need a client-side processing or mapReduce, but you are doing it right already.

Comment: Why do you want to use your data as key?  I  am just curious.

Comment: Iterate resulting cursor with `forEach`?

Comment: @user3100115 end goal is to pass the key as x-axis and value as the y-axis for a graph in chartkick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
db.restaurants.aggregate([
  {
    "$group" : {_id:"$cuisine", count_1:{$sum:1}}
  }
]).
result.
map(function(o) {
  var r = {};
  r[o._id] = o.count_1;
  return r;
});
```

Comment: I get this error: `2016-05-12T17:36:51.714+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] TypeError: db.restaurants.aggregate(...).result is undefined :
@(shell):1:1`

Comment: What does the output of `db.restaurants.aggregate([
  {
    "$group" : {_id:"$cuisine", count_1:{$sum:1}}
  }
])` look like for you? The output of `aggregate()` should always have the array `result`.

Comment: [i.imgur.com/pdUJlRm.png](http://i.imgur.com/pdUJlRm.png), I'm using the CLI client as well. I find it strange it doesn't give you the output as an object -- maybe a difference in version?

Comment: I guess so, I'm on the Windows client

Answer (score -1):

this will give you the expected output

```
db.restaurants.aggregate([
      {
        $group : {_id:"$cuisine", mycount:{$sum:1}}
      }]).map(function(o) {
      var r = {};
      r[o._id] = o.mycount;
      return r;
    });
```